# Most efficient method of working with a large number of images in Android

Tags: android, android-image

I'm working on a music player app for android and am trying to find the best way of dealing with images. I'm loading artist images from the web, and album images either from the MediaStore or the web depending on the circumstances. I will need to add either set of images (artist or album) to listViews at different times.

Storing the images in memory (HashTable) would make loading very quick, but could become impractical if the user has a very large music library.

However I can't load them on an "as needed" basis because I need to bind them to a listView. In addition, I have a notification that displays the artist image and provides navigation controls. If I wait to load the image when the user clicks the next button, it might not load before the notification view updates.

Is the best approach to connect to the Net on first load and then save the files locally, and then load them as needed? If I do it this way, will the image be loaded quickly enough to keep up with a user fast-clicking the next button and refreshing the artist image view?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a listview or gridview to display images.

You can use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader Universal Image Loader to load images either form MediaStore or from the web. Uses caching. Based on Lazy Loading but has more configuration options.

In you adapter contructor

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "UniversalImageLoader/Cache");


 // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
   imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
 // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
              // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
             .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
             .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
             .enableLogging()
             .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
    imageLoader.init(config);
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//dummy image
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
    .build();
```

In your getView()

```
      ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
      imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);
```

You can also use https://github.com/thest1/LazyList. Also uses caching.

Also use a ViewHolder in listview or grdiview. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan. A couple follow up questions.

Comment: 1) How does the caching work? Does it save a copy locally?
2) Do you suggest saving all of the images locally early in the process or just loading them from the web as needed?

Comment: caching is actually writing your image download to a location. Phone memory or sdcard. Your url is the key. if its present in cache. it display from cache. else download new image and display.

Comment: So if I use cacheOnDisc(), will the image be saved locally forever or just for the current session?

Thanks again.

Comment: it will cached on disc sd card under the folder UniversalImageLoader/Cache

Comment: u accepted and unaccepted the answer??. just curious to know why?

Comment: I didn't mean to unaccept the answer. I tried to accept David's answer as well and it removed the check from you. I guess I can't accept two answers?

Comment: ok. you can upvote by clickin on the up arrow. you can also set cache size limit. also unlimmited caching is the default option.

Comment: u need reputation 15 i guess to upvote. I forget about that. Anyways you can come back and upvote both the answers if both of them helps.

Comment: I gave you the check since you provided more details. Sorry David...restriction of the site. :(

Answer (score 0):

Load your images from local file storage or `MediaStore` in the `getView()` function of your `ListView's` `ListAdapter` or `SimpleListAdapter`. The adapter will take care of only calling `getView()` when necessary for the item(s) needed by `position`. Your system will be fast enough to load the images in this manner when they are needed.

You will have to fetch all images from the web at an earlier time and store them in the local filesystem so they are available for display by the `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks David! When I save the album images locally, should I just save them to a folder or update the MediaStore?

Comment: There are multiple places to save your album images, including local file system ("Internal Storage" i.e. your sandbox), the SD card (not guaranteed to be there, and public), and MediaStore (also public). I recommend the first method, unless you need the images shared outside of your app or you have many MB of them which would overwhelm the available internal storage. The path is hardwired to "openFileStream()" in any Android Activity. All the storage options are discussed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html